# Data takes long time to load- bootstrap datatable

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am using codeigniter bootstrap theme datatable to load data from database but it takes long time to load as it takes all data from database and then convert it in pagination. Is there any way to load 10 records at a time so that load time will get reduced?
Thanks

Comment: use ajax in datatable @priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, datatable has a Server-side processing option. When this is enabled, instead of loading all records to the browser, only the required records for displaying are fetched.

You need to set `serverSide` option to `true` and also provide an Ajax data source that accepts the required parameters and serve the contents in the prescribed format.

See an example from datatables official site [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).